# Getting eastern standard time in a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have an sql query as following

```
select A.bus_id as busid, A.stop_id as source, A.arrival as atime, B.arrival as dtime from
    (SELECT * from schedules as S where S.stop_id = #{startStopId}) A
    inner join
    (SELECT * from schedules as S where S.stop_id = #{endStopId}) B
    on A.bustag = B.bustag
    where A.arrival < B.arrival
    and A.arrival > localtime;
```

The issue is that i am living in eastern standard time zone (new york) but this local time seems to be local time of where the server is located. I am using clou9 to host my application and  i suspect they are using aws or something else maybe. I basically want to do A.arrival > eastern standard time.

I would appreciate suggestions. I was also wondering if it is possible to do it in this statement itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Option 1: No access to change settings:***

Give MySQL this command once a session to change to Eastern Timezone:

MySQL:

```
SET time_zone = 'America/New_York';
```

PHP:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

It has to be executed once a session so it can be a pain.

***Option 2: With Access to SSH as root:***

If it's a VPS and you have access to the full server as root, follow this procedure through SSH:

Stop MySQL and log into MySQL CLI:

```
service mysqld stop
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql -p
```

You'll then be in MySQL CLI:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'America/New_York';
mysql> exit
```

You'll be back in shell:

```
service mysqld start
```

Comment: If it's free, you probably don't have Shell access. You will have to use option 1.